# Xunit Setup of a method not working as expected

Tags: moq, xunit, xunit.net

I have just started on a new project and the solution doesn't have a single unit test. So I thought a good way for me to improve my below average skills in unit testing and to learn the application would be to write tests as I go along.

I haven't done too much with xunit before so this might be a simple question, I have searched for the answer myself however can't seem to find an answer.

Its a webapi project I am trying to test. The controller has a base controller that contains its methods for logging e.g.

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ILog _log;

    public BaseController(ILog log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }


    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)] 
    public virtual void Log(Enums.RequestType requestType, string detail)
    {
        _log.Info(string.Format("{0} | {1}",requestType, detail));
    }
```

From my controller

```
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult<MyDetail>> Get([FromUri]long id)
    {
        Enums.RequestType requestType = Enums.RequestType.GET;
        Log(requestType, "start called");
        var card = await _repository.FindItemAsync(id);
        Log(requestType, "thats a rap");
    }
```

My tests so far look like

```
    [Fact()]
    public void TestMyDetailsReturnsDetailAndLogs()
    {
        var detail = MockDetail();


        _myController = new Mock<MyDetailController>(_repository.Object, _logging.Object);
        _myController.Setup(m => m.Log(It.IsAny<Enums.RequestType>(),
                                        It.IsAny<string>()));



        _repository.Setup(x => x.FindItemAsync(It.IsAny<long>())
        .ReturnsAsync(detail);

        var controllerResult = _myController.Object.Get(detail.Id);
        _myController.VerifyAll();

        var negotiatedResult = controllerResult.Result;
        Assert.NotNull(negotiatedResult);
```

> Additional information: The following setups were not matched:

```
 MyController m => m.Log(It.IsAny<RequestType>(), It.IsAny<String>())
```

2 questions, why am I getting this message? as I have setup the m.Log

Should I my breakpoints within my controller and repository be getting hit?

Any help would be great!!

Answer (score 0):

I think since your controller is mocked, the Get method is not called and thus the inner implementation calls are not matched. Anyhow, if you're testing your Controller you shouldn't mock it, only it's dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You mocked your "_myController" but it should return something.
Accually you mock it because you want it return something that you want.

So add return to end. Fill inside of return with type log in your case.

_myController.Setup(m => m.Log(It.IsAny(),
                                        It.IsAny())).Return(XXX);

Example: Lets say Log return bool and you want log to return true. 
It would be something like that
_myController.Setup(m => m.Log(It.IsAny(),
                                        It.IsAny())).Return(true);